# Lógica - Dado 2 strings, como saber quantas movimentações eu faço quando transformo a primeira string na segunda

Tags: c#, lógica

Ola, tudo bem?
tenho 2 strings , e preciso que calcule o total de movimentações para se transformar a primeira string na segunda string

```
string palavra1 = "gato"
string palavra2 = "pato"
```

substituindo o “G” do gato “P” , transformo “gato” em “pato”.

mas também poderia ser as strings

```
string palavra1 = "cavalo";
string palavra2 = "pato";
```

Nesse caso o total de movimentações seria 4.
porque removeria C(1) e A(2) e trocaria V por P(3)e L por T(4)

Alguem pode me ajudar?
Abs,

Comment: Oi, eu não tenho conhecimento em C# (só trabalho com JavaScript), mas tente procurar algum tipo de função/biblioteca que faça algo como o site [Diff Checker](https://www.diffchecker.com). Nesse webapp você coloca dois dados: um texto original e outro alterado. Após a checagem, o número de letras removidas seria como o de movimentações que você mencionou. **Obs**.: Para efeito de teste, coloque uma letra por linha. Certamente deve haver uma implementação em sua linguagem.

Answer (score 0):

Um algoritmo que faz isso é o de *[Maior Subsequência Comum](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Maior%20Subsequ%C3%AAncia%20Comum&rlz=1C1CHZL_pt-BRBR744BR744&oq=Maior%20Subsequ%C3%AAncia%20Comum&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)* ou em inglês *[Longest Common Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)*.

O primeiro link, tive que apontar pra uma busca no Google, pois não achei uma referência mais imutável. No segundo, vai para a página da Wikipedia em inglês... mas tem alguns exemplos de implementação lá.

Esse algoritmo pode ser feito para comparar qualquer tipos de sequências, podendo ser duas strings, duas listas de strings representando as linhas de dois textos, etc.

Comment: Obrigado pela reposta Miguel, lendo aqui é isso mesmo a lógica que preciso fazer...porém o problema é encaixar essa logica no meu codigo c#.

Comment: Depois da resposta do Miguel, fui pesquisar sobre Longest Common Subsequence e achei esse artigo que me ajudou muito. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_subsequence

Valeu...

Comment: Legal esse site! ... Revendo a sua questão, se vc estiver interessado apenas na quantidade de alterações, também pode procurar sobre [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) ([Distância Levenshtein](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dist%C3%A2ncia_Levenshtein))

Comment: Alguém vem negativa e não fala nada... tá chato responder no SOPT ultimamente!